# which files to ignore using to commit to SVN in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, svn, subclipse

I have used Eclipse and SVN for a while. However, I'm still not clear which files/folders usually should be ignored while commit the whole project to repository. I know .project needs to be ignored. What about others? By the way this is an android project. However, answers to general project are also welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: are you looking way to make Eclipse  ignore the files?

Comment: @Sreekanthss I know the way to ignore the files in the team Synchronizing respective. I'm wondering which files don't need go to the repository, like .project. Want to get a list of file types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are using configuration as below to support different IDE:

```
# Eclipse related (and M2e)
.classpath
.project
.settings/
.metadata/
test-output/

# Maven related (and some plugins)
target/
*~
dist
*.ser
*.ec

# Intellij
*.ipr
*.iml
*.iws
.idea
.temp

# Other
.svn/
bin/
bak/
*.log
*.orig
*.versionsBackup
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically following list of files added in .gitignore file for android projects.

```
# Built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# Files for the Dalvik VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# Generated files
bin/
gen/

# Gradle files
.gradle/
build/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Proguard folder generated by Eclipse
proguard/
```